# Add new tab in custom module admin side after custom account in Magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, admin-panel, tabs

Can you Please guide how can I add new tab in admin side customer module with some custom attribute?

I create below files, But still not get anything, No tab added, Please check and correct me if anything goes wrong.

1) **app/code/local/Customtab/CustomerAccount/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
       <Customtab_CustomerAccount>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Customtab_CustomerAccount>
   </modules>
 <adminhtml>
    <layout>
           <updates>
               <customeraccount>
                  <file>customeraccount.xml</file>
               </customeraccount>
           </updates>
       </layout>
   </adminhtml>  
   <global>
       <blocks>
           <customeraccount>
               <class>Customtab_CustomerAccount_Block</class>
           </customeraccount>
       </blocks>
 </global>
</config>
```

2.) **app/etc/modules/Customtab_Customeraccount.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <config>
   <module>
  <Customtab_CustomerAccount>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
  </Customtab_CustomerAccount>
  </module>
  </config>
```

3.) **app/code/local/Customtab/CustomerAccount/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Action.php**

```
<?php 

    /**
     * Adminhtml customer insurance tab
     *
     */
    class Customtab_CustomerAccount_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Action
     extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
        implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->setTemplate('customeraccount/action.phtml');

        }

        public function getCustomtabInfo(){

            $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
            $customtab='Custom tab insurance settings is here';
            return $customtab;
            }

        /**
         * Return Tab label
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabLabel()
        {
            return $this->__('Insurance Settings');
        }

        /**
         * Return Tab title
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabTitle()
        {
            return $this->__('Insurance Tab');
        }

        /**
         * Can show tab in tabs
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function canShowTab()
        {
            $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
            return (bool)$customer->getId();
        }

        /**
         * Tab is hidden
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function isHidden()
        {
            return false;
        }

         /**
         * Defines after which tab, this tab should be rendered
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getAfter()
        {
            return 'tags';
        }

    }
    ?>
```

4.) **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customeraccount/action.phtml**

```
<div>
New Custom Tab
</div>
```

5.) **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customeraccount.xml**

customer_edit_tab_action
        customeraccount/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_action

Comment: have a look at this http://www.mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/

Comment: @Piyush, Please check my question I Edit it, Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: path `app/etc/module/Customtab_Customeraccount.xml` should be `app/etc/modules/Customtab_Customeraccount.xml`

Comment: @Piyush, Thanks for your link, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom module add below code in layout xml file

```
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <action method="addTab"><name>customtab_name</name><block>modulename/adminhtml_customer_tab</block></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

Create block file in your custom module

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Tab
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {
   /**
     * Set the template for the block
     *
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
       $this->setTemplate('template path here');
    }
   /**
     * Retrieve the label used for the tab relating to this block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('My Custom Tab');
    }
   /**
     * Retrieve the title used by this tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Click here to view your custom tab content');
    }
   /**
     * Determines whether to display the tab
     * Add logic here to decide whether you want the tab to display
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Stops the tab being hidden
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

add below code in file Customtab_Customeraccount.xml at `app/etc/modules/Customtab_Customeraccount.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Customtab_CustomerAccount>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends />
        </Customtab_CustomerAccount>
    </modules>
</config>
```

You need to change your **Action.php** below code

```
public function canShowTab()
        {
            $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
            return (bool)$customer->getId();
        }
```

to:

```
public function canShowTab()
        {

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Please check my question I Edit it, Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @yogita your code is correct any error there?

Comment: No Error, And I don't see any New tab in my customer module admin side.

Comment: The Path is right but Miss to mention : <config> and <module> in Customtab_Customeraccount.xml <br/>  Now Tab appears but only when I edit any customer not in add new customer, I want the tab in both.

Comment: @Yogita updated answer check it

Comment: Thanks. Let me know How Can I add Custom Fields / Attribute for this tab.

Comment: Ad simple input field there you will get that data in post